# Define a django model which use in a foreign key a specific instance of an other model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's take an example for my problem : the models of a blog.
I would have django models like this :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
```

My problem is how to define an other model which use a specific category. For example, how to define a Cook model, based on the Article model thanks to inheritance, but which only used the category 'cook'.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://djangodays.com/2009/05/11/django-foreign-key-default-value-example/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete my comment:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def cook_category():
    return Category.objects.get(name='cook')

class CookArticle(models.Model):
    #your model
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=cook_category)
```